# How to implement interstitial ads in android but Start.io ads not Admob?

Tags: java, android, interstitial

I want to have interstitial ads on the onclick between two activities. how to do it. but the ads i want to have is start.io ads.

Comment: https://support.start.io/hc/en-us/articles/360005105013-Mopub#step-6-testing-your-integration-0-13 check this link

Comment: is that the answer of my questin.  LoL

Comment: it might be an answer